# PC bootstrap process step by step

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system

The bootstrapping process is a bit confusing, I hope I understand it correctly. I will try to describe my understandings and hopefully can be corrected. As this is an extremely important and I want to dive into the small details.

**BIOS:**
It sets up an **interrupt descriptor table** and **initializes various devices**. After initializing all the important devices the BIOS knows about, it searches for a `bootable` device such as a floppy, hard drive, or CD-ROM.
Hard disks are divided into 512 bytes regions called `sectors` and the first sector is known as `boot-sector`. Once the BIOS finds a bootable floppy or hard disk, it loads the 512-byte boot sector into memory, then passes control to the boot loader.

**Boot-loader:**
 1. The boot loader switches the processor from real mode to 32-bit protected mode, because it is only in this mode that software can access all the memory above 1MB in the processor's physical address space. 
 2. The boot loader reads the kernel from the hard disk

**Kernel:**
The kernel begins with some assembly language code that sets things up so that C language code can execute properly. And enables `paging`.

```
Memory layout

|---------|
|         |
|   boat  | Sector 0
|  loader |
|         |
|---------|
|         |
|         |
|         | Sector 1
     .
     .
     .
```

My questions:

1. How does the boot-loader know where is the kernel found ? 

    From what I remember, an `ELF` header contains the number of sectors the boatloader should load. But how does it find this `ELF` header ?
   What structures does it use to find these details ?
2. The Bios is located on an `EEPROM` chip, yet some books like to show that BIOS is on the first sector in hard disk and bootloader is on second. This confuses me a bit.
3. Is the Kernel always brought into the same address in main-memory ? if so who/what determines this address ?
4. Is the boot-loader always brought to `0x0000 - 0x7c00` block of memory ?

Any additional information about the flow will be welcomed. And I am sure I missed some responsibilities of these 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the boot-loader know where is the kernel found ?

Actually, the 512 bytes boot-loader does not load the OS kernel itself but the second boot-loader stage. This second stage is what is usually known as *the boot-loader*. It may be the Windows `bootmgt` or `grub` or `lilo` or a bunch of others. This boot-loader is usually located in a fixed place in the disk, sometimes the second sector, sometimes the second cylincer...

Then, the details vary, but usually that bigger boot-loader loads a configuration file that tells them where the real kernel is. Sometimes it even includes code to read a full filesystem.

> The Bios is located on an EEPROM chip, yet some books like to show that BIOS is on the first sector.

Maybe they are mixing the first stage boot-sector in the first sector with the second stage boot-loader in the next few sectors?

> Is the Kernel always brought into the same address in main-memory?
>   Is the boot-loader always brought to 0x0000 - 0x7c00 block of memory ?

In a standard 32-bit PC, the boot sector is always loaded at address `0000:7C00`, still in real-mode. That is a standard PC convention, from the IBM-PC days.
Then, it will load the second stage in whatever memory it will decide and pass on. That's why every time you install a boot-loader you have to rewrite the boot-sector too.
Some boot-loaders will switch to protected mode and load the OS directly, while others will work in real-mode and the OS kernel will switch to protected mode and move itself to upper memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still find it odd why is the kernel located in high addresses. Could you elaborate please ? whats the reason behind this ?

Comment: @TonyTannous: what do you mean with _located_? The kernel is first loaded in low memory because it is still real mode and it is the only memory accesible. Then it moves to high mem to free the limited low mem, needed for some legacy devices and/or some kinds of DMA (don't know if still true on modern systems).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I read somewhere it is moved into a higher portion of the memory for a reason (for legacy we free the 1mb) I understand that. I guess then there's no special reason afterall. (besides legacy).

Comment: Well legacy and DMA are quite special, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

1. As far as i understand The Bootloader (at least grub) Uses the file system and a path set in the config file to determine the file to load
2. The Bios Is Located on a EEPROM chip, the book is probably just written confusing.
3. As far as i understand it isn't but it has the same address in its [Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) (not sure about that)
4. as far as i know the [Master Boot Record](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning#Master_Boot_Record) is At the beginning of a Harddrive which usually contains the first stage of the boot loader.